# How to force users to logout after X minutes of inactivity using Rules, Views?

Tags: 7, views, users, rules

How to force users to logout after X minutes of inactivity using Rules, Views or any other popular module ?

---

*update 2012-01-27*

Where can I find an example how to do the forced session expire using Rules module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Drupalmodules.com](http://drupalmodules.com) shows two potential modules:

[Session Expire](http://drupal.org/project/session_expire) - "Expires rows from the session table older than a certain time."

[Automated Logout](http://drupal.org/project/autologout) - "This module provides a site administrator the ability to log users out after a specified time of inactivity."

Either module would probably be able to give you the functionality you want. The automated logout module looks like it could give you a timer to show how much longer a user has before being logged out.

Comment: Thank you, I will check Session Expire and Automated Logout as well. However I wonder if there is a way how to set this up using Rules (and a custom action maybe?), instead of adding another module for this purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

Add some PHP-Code to the rule, if interested I could also provide a rules export.

```
global $user;

// Session longer than 3 hours
if ((REQUEST_TIME - 10800) > $user->timestamp) {
  module_load_include('pages.inc', 'user');
  user_logout();
}
```